# After drawing a circle on Google map, how to zoom in to the level that barely contains the circle?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I draw a 3-mile-radius circle at a specified location but the zoom level shows the entire USA and the Pacific and Atlantic Oceans.  If I zoom in manually via the UI scale widget, the circle is where it should be and is the correct size. I thought `fitBounds()` zoomed in automatically?  If an explicit call to `setZoom()` is required, how to calculate the correct zoom-level to encompass the entire circle without showing too much of the area outside the circle?

```
function setInitialMapFocusByZipcode(zipcode, desiredRadius)
{

   geocoder.geocode(
   { 'address': zipcode }, function (results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        usmap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

        var circ = new google.maps.Circle({
          map:  usmap,              
          fillOpacity: 0.25
        });
        circ.setRadius(desiredRadius * 1609.344); // desiredRadius=3 in testing
        circ.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);                     
        usmap.fitBounds(circ.getBounds());

    } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: [Your code works for me](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_zoomToCircle.html)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to check. Possibly a browser issue.

Comment: Does my example show the same issue in your browser (and what browser is it you are using)?  I checked it in Firefox an IE on my computer.

Comment: It was interference from a third-party UI control. It's working now. Thank you.

Comment: There was no way to determine that from the information posted...

Comment: Of course not -- I didn't even think of it as a possible cause until after I'd asked the question, and I returned here to post the findings as soon as I realized it and tested. Map has to be fully visible in order for fitBounds to work. It cannot be on an expanding panel.